# Assembly: Replace substring with another string

Tags: string, assembly, replace, substring

Hi i'm new in Assembly and i've some problems with an exercise asking me to find a substring in an original string then, if found, replace it with another given string, but only for odd occurrences found(1,3,5...). I.E.

- Original string: "abc world def world".
- String to find: "world"
- String substitution: "cat"
- Output: "acb cat def world"

Also, these should work for all kind of inputs. Even if, like in this case, "world" is longer then "cat", i need to replace "world" entirely("catld" would be wrong).
Can anyone help me?! I've no idea how to procede.
Here is my code at the moment, i'm still not considering the odd occurrences, i'm just trying to make it work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    //Input
    char stringa[1024] ="This string is a string\n";
    char str1[] ="string";  
    char str2[] ="cat"; 

    //Output
    char result[1024];

    __asm {

        XOR EAX, EAX
        CLD
        LEA ESI, str1
        LEA EDI, stringa
Ciclo:  MOV AL, [ESI]
        REPNZ SCASB
        DEC EDI
        PUSH EDI
        PUSH ESI
        MOV ECX, 7
        REPE CMPSB
        CMP ECX, 0
        POP ESI
        JZ Sost
        JMP Ciclo

Sost:   LEA ESI, str2
        POP EDI
        MOV ECX, 7
        REP MOVSB
    }

    printf("New string: %s\n",result);
}
```

Comment: Tell us what is the problem with the code you posted. Doesn't it replace anything? Does it replace wrongly?

Comment: It will not even compile in the form in which it is posted. (Not sure if it's just so unfinished, or it was eaten during copy/paste.. what's so problematic about Ctrl+A Ctrl+C in text editor, then Ctrl+V Ctrl+K in stackoverflow edit window? @OP: so you wrote some instructions, but I don't see any algorithm explanation. Write down first some english comments how it will work (each comment should be "simple" enough to be covered by 2-10 asm instructions at most).

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't make any sense. I'd recommend writing the algorithm in a higher-level language first, then translating it to assembly.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code, and i see only now(!!) that there is a result string to store the new string, that should help me. The code is unfinished because i'm actullay finding no solution. At the moment this code find the first right occurrence in the original string and replace it, but in the wrong way "catld". And then there is to think about the odd occurrences.

Comment: yeah, but even that limited functionality is "by accident", for example try it on string "ab wo wo world def world", and it will crash, or "abc" to get it into infinite loop/crash, etc... there are too many problems. Write the algorithm first, in plain english, what you plan to do. Before any ASM. Output string buffer will help a lot in cases like "short" -> "longer" word, where original string would be too short.

Comment: I mean, it's easy to write you correct solution (would take me probably between 20-30min), but what's the point. This is exercise to verify that you learned it, so show you did. It's fine to help you with particular small detail, but to write full code... well, usually I'm paid [well] for that.

Comment: why does abc becomes acb in your correct output?, you said for odd occurences only, but you have replace first "world" string which is a 2nd string?, did you start with zero?

Comment: @Ped7g - Absolutely right, i'm not asking you to write solution for me. I've got something in mind but when i start with code many details take me far from what i thinked. However i've 2 weeks time to resolve three exercices. Tomorrow i will write the algorithm and post it here to see if it's decent. For the moment the problem is that lessons and slides have been really not enought to reach the goal.

Comment: rcd - abc to acb is just a typing mistake. About the occurrences i mean that the first time i match "world" i have to replace it, the scond time i don't, the third time yes and so on.

Comment: oh ok, anyways for problems like this what i do is ill write it in C first so its easy to prototype, plus lots of functions available, then convert the algo. to assembly. you should also choose the best debugger for you, this is a must

Comment: Hi, I've updated with the algorithm, or what it is...

Comment: Another edit to my answer, I replaced "i" and "j" by "ebx" and "ecx" respectively, still work great.

Comment: @Ped7g - Can we talk privately for an exercise?

Comment: @caramelleamare: maybe, depends on several details (mostly my mood + time schedule, and your capability to show effort and progress). Fill up some contact info in your profile.

Comment: @Ped7g - Ok, let's see. I updated my profile. You can find my mail there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next code does the job: it finds and replaces all (not odd) occurrences of one string by another and leaves the resulting string in another variable, tested it in compiler EMU8086 (my VS is not working), explanation after the code :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
original db 'abc world def world xyz',0
find     db 'world',0
subst    db 'cat',0
result   db 100 dup(0)
i        dw ?             ;INDEX FOR "ORIGINAL".
j        dw ?             ;INDEX FOR "RESULT".
.code
   mov  ax, @data
   mov  ds, ax
   mov  i, offset original ;"I" POINTS TO "ORIGINAL".
   mov  j, offset result   ;"J" POINTS TO "RESULT".
;SEARCH VARIABLE "FIND" AT CURRENT POSITION ("I").
   mov  si, i
   lea  di, find
search:                        
   mov  al, [di]        ;CURRENT CHAR OF VARIABLE "FIND".
;CHECK IF END OF "FIND".
   cmp  al, 0           ;IF CURRENT CHAR OF "FIND" IS LAST ONE...
   je   match           ;... VARIABLE "FIND" WAS FOUND.
;CHECK IF END OF "ORIGINAL".
   cmp  [si], 0
   je   finale
;CONTINUE.   
   cmp  [si], al        ;CMP ORIGINAL[SI],FIND[DI].
   jne  mismatch        ;CHARS ARE DIFFERENT.
   inc  si              ;NEXT CHAR OF "ORIGINAL".
   inc  di              ;NEXT CHAR OF "FIND".
   jmp  search          ;REPEAT (COMPARE NEXT CHAR).
match:
;WHEN "FIND" IS FOUND, "SUBST" REPLACE IT IN "RESULT".
   mov  i, si           ;SKIP "FIND" IN "ORIGINAL", BUT...
   dec  i               ;...SKIPPED ON CHAR FORWARD (SO DECREASE).
   lea  di, subst       ;STRING TO REPLACE "FIND".
replace:
   mov  al, [di]        ;CURRENT CHAR OF VARIABLE "SUBST".
;CHECK IF END OF "SUBST".
   cmp  al, 0           ;IF CURRENT CHAR OF "FIND" IS LAST ONE...
   je   next
;CONTINUE.
   mov  si, j           ;CURRENT POSITION IN "RESULT".
   mov  [si], al        ;COPY CHAR INTO "RESULT[ J ]".
   inc  j               ;NEXT POSITION IN "RESULT".
   inc  di              ;NEXT POSITION IN "SUBST".
   jmp  replace
mismatch:    
;APPEND CURRENT CHAR (AL) INTO "RESULT".
   mov  si, i           ;CURRENT POSITION IN "ORIGINAL".
   mov  di, j           ;CURRENT POSITION IN "RESULT".
   mov  al, [si]
   mov  [di], al
   inc  j               ;"I" IS ALSO INCREMENTED 4 LINES BELOW.
;NEXT CHAR IN "ORIGINAL".
next:
   lea  di, find        ;SEARCH AGAIN VARIABLE "FIND".
   inc  i               ;NEXT CHAR IN "ORIGINAL".
;CHECK IF END OF "ORIGINAL".
   mov  si, i
   cmp  [si], 0
   jne  search          ;REPEAT (SEARCH "FIND" AGAIN).
;END OF WHOLE PROCESS.
finale:
   mov  ax, 4c00h
   int  21h
```

The result is :

```
original = `abc world def world xyz`
find     = `world`
subst    = `cat`
result   = `abc cat def cat xyz`
```

Notice in the code all strings (the variables in data segment) use `0` as end delimiter. This is very important, because this is the key to work with strings of any size, not hardcoded sizes.

Now the algorithm :

1. It loops over each character in "original".
2. The string "find" is searched when each char in "original" is visited.
3. If "find" is not found, the current char in "original" is appended in "result".
4. If "find" is found, the string "subst" is appended in "result", and "i" (the pointer to "original") skips to where the search loop ended (minus 1), in order to skip the string we want to replace. "j" (the pointer to "result") never skips, it always increases by one.

To make it work for odd occurrences, add another numeric variable as counter that increases under label `match:`, if the variable is not odd right after label `search:`, make it jump to label `next:`.

Edit: now the Visual Studio 2013 version (tested on a "C++ Win32 console application"):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{  //Input
    char original[1024] = "abc world def world xyz\n";
    char find[]         = "world";
    char subst[]        = "cat";
   //Output
    char result[1024]   = { 0 };
    int i;
    int j;

    _asm { lea  esi, original
           mov  i, esi             // "I" POINTS TO "ORIGINAL".
           lea  esi, result
           mov  j, esi              // "J" POINTS TO "RESULT".
        // SEARCH VARIABLE "FIND" AT CURRENT POSITION ("I").
           mov  esi, i
           lea  edi, find
        search:                        
           mov  al, [edi]          // CURRENT CHAR OF VARIABLE "FIND".
        // CHECK IF END OF "FIND".
           cmp  al, 0              // IF CURRENT CHAR OF "FIND" IS LAST ONE...
           je   match              // ... VARIABLE "FIND" WAS FOUND.
        // CHECK IF END OF "ORIGINAL".
           cmp  [esi], 0
           je   finale
        // CONTINUE.   
           cmp  [esi], al       // CMP ORIGINAL[SI],FIND[DI].
           jne  mismatch        // CHARS ARE DIFFERENT.
           inc  esi              // NEXT CHAR OF "ORIGINAL".
           inc  edi              // NEXT CHAR OF "FIND".
           jmp  search          // REPEAT (COMPARE NEXT CHAR).
        match:
        // WHEN "FIND" IS FOUND, "SUBST" REPLACE IT IN "RESULT".
           mov  i, esi          // SKIP "FIND" IN "ORIGINAL", BUT...
           dec  i               // ...SKIPPED ON CHAR FORWARD (SO DECREASE).
           lea  edi, subst      // STRING TO REPLACE "FIND".
        replace:
           mov  al, [edi]       // CURRENT CHAR OF VARIABLE "SUBST".
        // CHECK IF END OF "SUBST".
           cmp  al, 0           // IF CURRENT CHAR OF "FIND" IS LAST ONE...
           je   next
        // CONTINUE.
           mov  esi, j          // CURRENT POSITION IN "RESULT".
           mov  [esi], al       // COPY CHAR INTO "RESULT[ J ]".
           inc  j               // NEXT POSITION IN "RESULT".
           inc  edi             // NEXT POSITION IN "SUBST".
           jmp  replace
        mismatch:    
        // APPEND CURRENT CHAR (AL) INTO "RESULT".
           mov  esi, i          // CURRENT POSITION IN "ORIGINAL".
           mov  edi, j          // CURRENT POSITION IN "RESULT".
           mov  al, [esi]
           mov  [edi], al
           inc  j               // "I" IS ALSO INCREMENTED 4 LINES BELOW.
        // NEXT CHAR IN "ORIGINAL".
        next:
           lea  edi, find       // SEARCH AGAIN VARIABLE "FIND".
           inc  i               // NEXT CHAR IN "ORIGINAL".
        // CHECK IF END OF "ORIGINAL".
           mov  esi, i
           cmp  [esi], 0
           jne  search          // REPEAT (SEARCH "FIND" AGAIN).
        // END OF WHOLE PROCESS.
        finale:       
    }
    printf("New string: %s", result );
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit #2 : previous code with variables `i` and `j` replaced by `ebx` and `ecx` respectively (I left the parts where the comments say "I" and "J" so you can see where I made the replacements):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{  //Input
    char original[1024] = "abc world def world xyz\n";
    char find[]         = "world";
    char subst[]        = "cat";
   //Output
    char result[1024]   = { 0 };

    _asm { lea  esi, original
           mov  ebx, esi            // "I" POINTS TO "ORIGINAL".
           lea  esi, result
           mov  ecx, esi            // "J" POINTS TO "RESULT".
        // SEARCH VARIABLE "FIND" AT CURRENT POSITION ("I").
           mov  esi, ebx
           lea  edi, find
        search:                        
           mov  al, [edi]          // CURRENT CHAR OF VARIABLE "FIND".
        // CHECK IF END OF "FIND".
           cmp  al, 0              // IF CURRENT CHAR OF "FIND" IS LAST ONE...
           je   match              // ... VARIABLE "FIND" WAS FOUND.
        // CHECK IF END OF "ORIGINAL".
           cmp  [esi], 0
           je   finale
        // CONTINUE.   
           cmp  [esi], al       // CMP ORIGINAL[SI],FIND[DI].
           jne  mismatch        // CHARS ARE DIFFERENT.
           inc  esi             // NEXT CHAR OF "ORIGINAL".
           inc  edi             // NEXT CHAR OF "FIND".
           jmp  search          // REPEAT (COMPARE NEXT CHAR).
        match:
        // WHEN "FIND" IS FOUND, "SUBST" REPLACE IT IN "RESULT".
           mov  ebx, esi        // SKIP "FIND" IN "ORIGINAL", BUT...
           dec  ebx             // ...SKIPPED ON CHAR FORWARD (SO DECREASE).
           lea  edi, subst      // STRING TO REPLACE "FIND".
        replace:
           mov  al, [edi]       // CURRENT CHAR OF VARIABLE "SUBST".
        // CHECK IF END OF "SUBST".
           cmp  al, 0           // IF CURRENT CHAR OF "FIND" IS LAST ONE...
           je   next
        // CONTINUE.
           mov  esi, ecx        // CURRENT POSITION IN "RESULT".
           mov  [esi], al       // COPY CHAR INTO "RESULT[ J ]".
           inc  ecx             // NEXT POSITION IN "RESULT".
           inc  edi             // NEXT POSITION IN "SUBST".
           jmp  replace
        mismatch:    
        // APPEND CURRENT CHAR (AL) INTO "RESULT".
           mov  esi, ebx        // CURRENT POSITION IN "ORIGINAL".
           mov  edi, ecx        // CURRENT POSITION IN "RESULT".
           mov  al, [esi]
           mov  [edi], al
           inc  ecx             // "I" IS ALSO INCREMENTED 4 LINES BELOW.
        // NEXT CHAR IN "ORIGINAL".
        next:
           lea  edi, find       // SEARCH AGAIN VARIABLE "FIND".
           inc  ebx             // NEXT CHAR IN "ORIGINAL".
        // CHECK IF END OF "ORIGINAL".
           mov  esi, ebx
           cmp  [esi], 0
           jne  search          // REPEAT (SEARCH "FIND" AGAIN).
        // END OF WHOLE PROCESS.
        finale:       
    }
    printf("New string: %s", result );
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also my given variables terminate whit 0, yes this is important, thanks.

Comment: ...Thanks for this code, i will try to make my algorithm works using some details of your. If i fail i will use this code(in Lab we have only worked in VS, and it's what i'm using now).

Comment: I've update my code. Thanks, but i've done by my self rigth now! I suppose it's an awful code, but it works! I'v tried the some different input and it always return a ggod output. Tomorrow i'll try to reduce the code because there are many repeated lined of code, but i don't know if i'll succeed. What i didn't tell you is that i CANNOT add any variable, i mus use only the inputs one! However thanks, your code helped me.

Comment: Bad news! I thought the code was good, but it wasn't. If i change char[] str1 in char[1024] str1, it doesn't work, obviously. So i've changed the code using '/0' to find the end of the string, instead of function LENGTH, and it seemed good. But still not! ...

Comment: ...At point i'm now, it doesn't work whit inputs: char[] stringa = "a"(original), char[] str1 = "a"(to find), char[] str2 = "b"(new string). There is an index problem that i'm pretty sure i cannot repair without demaging  something else. So i have to write a new algorithm, i think. As i said before, i cannot add any variables like Josè Manuel did using "i" and "j" to store the pointers. Should i post the code as it is now? But i think it's not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I thought something like this:
Inputs: original string, substring to find, substring for replacement, output string

1. Set EDI to first byte pointed by original string
2. Set ESI to first byte pointed by substring to find
3. Move to AL the first substring byte
4. Read the original string until different from the first char of the given substring to find(SCASB).
5. While different, copy every char into output string.
6. When/If they match, set ECX to substring length.
7. Compare original and substring, starting from the point of the first match.
8. Check ECX.
9. If ECX is zero, i've an occurrence, so go to Checkpoint.
10. Go to point 4.

Checkpoint:  a) Increment occurrence counter
             b) Check counter.
             c) If odd go to Replacement.
             d) Go to point 4

Replacement: a) Set ECX to replacement string length
             b) Copy the replacement string in the output string
             c) Go to point 4

How does it look like?

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  This kind of high-level planning out how your code will work is exactly what you should be doing before writing actual instructions, so you're on the right track.  You might discover a flaw in your high-level reasoning after implementing and debugging, but that happens.  Or you might discover that there's a more efficient way to do things once you start thinking about the implementation details; that's also common.  In that case it's up to you whether you finish less-efficient way or go back and tweak the high-level design so you can gain efficiency somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I don't how but i wrote a code that works for what exercise asks. I'll add the code in a few minutes here.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, I've tried many inputs. There are a lot of repeated lines of code but it works. I will see if i can reduce it next days. As i said to Josè, i CANNOT add variables to the 4 strings given in input: stringa(original), str1(to find), str2(new substring), risultato(final output):

```
    __asm {
                XOR EAX, EAX
                XOR EBX, EBX
                XOR EDX, EDX
                CLD
                LEA EDI, str1
                LEA ESI, stringa

                Cicle : 
                        MOV AL, [ESI]
    //CHECK IF STRING ENDED
                        CMP AL, 0
                        JZ End
    //CHECK THE CHAR
                        SCASB
    //IF THEY DON'T MATCH GO TO COPY CHAR
                        JNZ Append
    //OTHERWISE CHECK IF FROM HERE STRINGS ARE EQUAL
                        MOV ECX, LENGTH str1
                        DEC EDI
                        REPE CMPSB
                        CMP ECX, 0
    //IF YES GO TO CHECK IF IT'S AN ODD OCCURRENCE
                        JZ Checkpoint
    //IF NOT GET BACK ESI AND EDI...
                        NEG ECX
                        ADD ECX, LENGTH str1
                        SUB EDI, ECX
                        SUB ESI, ECX
    //..AND COPY THE SINGLE CHAR
                        MOV risultato[EBX], AL
                        INC EBX
                        INC ESI
                        JMP Cicle

    //COPY CHAR WHEN STRINGS DONT'MATCH    
                Append :
                        INC ESI
                        DEC EDI
                        MOV risultato[EBX], AL
                        INC EBX
                        JMP Cicle

    //CHEK IF ODD/EVEN OCCURRENCE               
                Checkpoint :
                        INC EDX
                        TEST EDX, 00000001h
    //IF ODD GO TO REPLACE ALL SUBSTRING
                        JNZ Replacement
    //OTHERWISE GET BACK ESI/EDI AND COPY THE SAME SUBSTRING TO RESULT
                        SUB EDI, LENGTH str1
                        SUB ESI, LENGTH str1
                        PUSH EDI
                        LEA EDI, risultato[EBX]
                        MOV ECX, LENGTH str1
                        REP MOVSB
    //UPDATE RESULT INDEX COUNTER
                        ADD EBX, LENGTH str1 - 1
    //GET BACK EDI POINTER
                        POP EDI
                        DEC ESI
                        JMP Cicle

    //REPLACEMENT OF THE SUBSTRING                  
                Replacement :
    //GET BACK EDI AT FIRST CHAR AND STORE ESI/EDI FOR NEXT LOOP
                        SUB EDI, LENGTH str1
                        PUSH ESI
                        PUSH EDI
    //SET A POINTER TO THE NEW STRING AND COPY IT TO RESULT
                        LEA ESI, str2
                        LEA EDI, risultato[EBX]
                        MOV ECX, LENGTH str2
                        REP MOVSB
    //UPDATE RESULT COUNTER AND GET BACK EDI/ESI TO PREVIOUS POSITIONS TO CONTINUE
                        ADD EBX, LENGTH str2 - 1
                        POP EDI
                        POP ESI
                        DEC ESI
                        JMP Cicle

                End :
                        MOV risultato[EBX], 0
}
```

I've forgotted a detail: when i find char 'è' this code rappresents it(in AL) with ascii 232 instead of 138, why? What can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's ok. I worked on Jose Manuel's code(thanks), i've modified it using pop/push instead of variables "i" and "j". Then it was failing the online test with input: "ccccc", "cc", "f". Result should be "fccc" but was "fcf". So i fixed some other details and now it's ok.

```
        XOR ECX, ECX
        XOR EAX, EAX
        XOR EBX, EBX
        XOR EDX, EDX
        LEA ESI, result
        PUSH ESI                //store result into stack
        LEA ESI, original       //esi points to original
        LEA EDI, find           //edi points to find

        Search :
            MOV AL, [EDI]
                CMP AL, 0           //chek if the end of find
                JE Match            //if yes, we have an occurrence
                CMP[ESI], 0         //check if end of original
                JE Mismatch         //if yes, coopy last char going to Mismatch
                CMP[ESI], al        //check if char match
                JNE Mismatch        //if yes go to Mismatch
                INC ESI             //else repeat Search to check if next char match
                INC EDI
                INC ECX             //chars counter
                JMP Search

        Match :
            INC EBX                 //occurrences counter
                TEST EBX, 00000001h
                JZ Mismatch         //if even go to Mismatch else continue...
                LEA EDI, str2       //else point to new string to replace
                MOV EDX, ESI        //copy the current original pointer
                POP ESI             //store it also into the stack

        Replacement :
            MOV AL, [EDI]           //copy new string char by char
                CMP AL, 0
                JE SetRegister      //if end of new string, get back the pointers
                MOV[ESI], AL        //else continue...
                INC ESI
                INC EDI
                JMP Replacement

        Mismatch :
            POP EDI                 //edi points to result
                SUB ESI, ECX        //set esi to the char it was pointing before Search or Match
                INC ECX             //shows how many chars we need to replace
                REP MOVSB           //ready to copy chars from original to result
                PUSH EDI
                CMP[ESI], 0         //check if original has ended
                JZ Fine
                DEC ESI
                XOR ECX, ECX        //set to zero the chars counter
                JMP Next            //go to Next char

        SetRegister :
            PUSH ESI                //after replacement set registers right positions
                MOV ESI, EDX
                DEC ESI
                XOR ECX, ECX

        Next :
            LEA EDI, find           //ready to find next char
                INC ESI
                CMP[ESI], 0
                JNE Search

        Fine :
            POP EDI
                MOV[EDI], 0         //close the result string
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Absolutely, sorry i do not often write in forums, so... you're right, i upvoted your answer. What is "accepting your answer"? Now i want to try if also your last edit version pass the test, i'm curios...

Comment: "accepting" is when you click the checkmark under the vote arrows.  Like most topics, google for "stack overflow accept answer" if you want to learn more.